# Use lapply for an if/else statement on a nested list in R

Tags: r, list, if-statement, lapply

In R, I am trying to extract POINTs from a nested list containing lists and doubles.

Here is an example of code to create the nested list structure:

```
library(sf)

GROUP    <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
DISTANCE <- c(709, 2283, 5515, 3035, 4471)
LONG     <- c(20.5, 29.4, -14.3, 9.85, -5.5)
LAT      <- c(-19.6, 1.6, 10.9, 2.3, 7.5)
Africa.groups <- data.frame(GROUP, DISTANCE, LONG, LAT)

nums <-  combn(nrow(Africa.groups), 2, FUN=\(x) {i <- x[1]; j <- x[2];   
  P0 <- as.numeric(Africa.groups[i, c("LONG", "LAT")])
  P1 <- as.numeric(Africa.groups[j, c("LONG", "LAT")])
  dists  <- Africa.groups[c(i,j), "DISTANCE"]*1000 ## in meters
  points <- st_sfc(st_point(P0), st_point(P1), crs = 4326)
  buffer  <- st_buffer(x = points, dist = dists, nQuadSegs = 180)
  # extract the feature coordinates of the polygon - we need to intersect lines, not polygons
  coordsB <- st_cast(buffer[[1]], 'LINESTRING')
  coordsC <- st_cast(buffer[[2]], 'LINESTRING')
  # find intersections
  coords <- st_intersection(x = coordsB, y = coordsC)
  nums   <- list(coords)
  }  )
```

The first two nested lists of `nums` shown here are representative of the two situations that are found and form the basis of my if/else attempts to extract and compile the POINTs.

```
[[1]]
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (LINESTRING (16.44059 -14.44397, 16.44059 -14.53416), POINT (27.26761 -18.92559))

[[2]]
MULTIPOINT ((27.12648 -18.25077), (20.33088 -26.06643), (27.17353 -18.24369))
```

In words: if the class (at the second spot) of a nested list in `nums` is "MULTIPOINT", then for that nested list extract the POINTs. Otherwise for the nested list, extract the second sub-nested list (which here excluded LINESTRINGS and only grabs POINTs).

Attempt 1:

```
result <-  lapply(length(nums), FUN=\(x) {i <- x[1];   
  if (class(nums[[i]])[2] == "MULTIPOINT") multi <- st_cast(st_sfc(nums[[i]]), 'POINT') else 
  multi <- nums[[i]][[2]]
  }  )
```

Attempt 2:

```
numbers <- for (i in length(nums)) {
  if (class(nums[[i]])[2] == "MULTIPOINT") {
    multi <- st_cast(st_sfc(nums[[i]]), 'POINT')
    numbs <- list(multi)
  }
  else {
   spots <- nums[[i]][[2]]
   number <- list(spots)
  }
  numbers <- list(numbs, number)
}
```

So, I want to grab the POINTs from each nested list in `nums` (the approach depending on the nested list type) and append them all into one long dataframe with two columns: Long, Lat.
For example, from `nums[[1]]` I just want `27.26761 -18.92559`, and from `nums[[2]]` I want `27.12648 -18.25077`, `20.33088 -26.06643`, and `27.17353 -18.24369`, so the resulting dataframe of these two will be:

```
    Long      Lat
1 27.26761 -18.92559
2 27.12648 -18.25077
3 20.33088 -26.06643
4 27.17353 -18.24369
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
point_geoms = lapply(nums, function(e){st_collection_extract(e,"POINT")})
```

will extract all POINT and MULTIPOINT geometries from the elements, with a few warnings where elements aren't GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONs but they can be ignored.

You can then apply `st_coordinates` to get a list of coordinate matrices:

```
> xymats = lapply(point_geoms, st_coordinates)
> xymats[[1]]
            X         Y
[1,] 27.26761 -18.92559
> xymats[[2]]
            X         Y L1
[1,] 27.12648 -18.25077  1
[2,] 20.33088 -26.06643  1
[3,] 27.17353 -18.24369  1
```

If you want to strip off the `L1` column (which is used for reconstructing MULTI- geometries) and bind everything into one big matrix that's this one-liner from `point_geoms` above:

```
> xymats = do.call(rbind, lapply(point_geoms, function(e)st_coordinates(e)[,1:2]))
> xymats
             X          Y
 [1,] 27.26761 -18.925593
 [2,] 27.12648 -18.250773
 [3,] 20.33088 -26.066426
 [4,] 27.17353 -18.243687
 [5,] 15.87600 -24.433809
```